# Flatten kronecker product in CAS?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-algebra-systems, maxima-software

I am a new user of Maxima, and I need to trace the elements of a big messy kronecker product of symbolic matrices.

I tried the following to get my feet wet, but I don't get a simple, flat matrix --

A:matrix([[a, b], [c, d]]);

Ak:mat_fullunblocker(kronecker_product(A, ident(2)));

Does anyone know how to get a "flat" or unblocked or whatever-you-call-it matrix out of Ak instead of the nested mess that Maxima returns?

Currently the result is this:

$$\pmatrix{\left[ \pmatrix{a&0\cr 0&a\cr } , \pmatrix{b&0\cr 0&b\cr }
  \right] &\left[ \pmatrix{c&0\cr 0&c\cr } , \pmatrix{d&0\cr 0&d\cr }
  \right] \cr }$$

I want this:

$$ \pmatrix{a&0&b&0\cr 0&a&0&b\cr c&0&d&0\cr 0&c&0&d} $$

I would also happily entertain recommendations for other CAS systems.  I don't need much, mostly just a crutch with some symbolic linear algebra.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a Maxima user, but from its documentation, perhaps you may try to change the line A:matrix([[a, b], [c, d]]); to A:matrix([a, b], [c, d]);

Comment: Yep, that works.  So far.  I find Maxima pretty counter intuitive, but my intuition was never particularly great anyway....

Comment: @user1551: Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).